# Different JS animation every time users refresh the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a little animation on my website to increment numbers, see http://jsfiddle.net/zQ5AL/
What I'd like to do is to have 2-3 different animations (actually same animation but numberValue and text would be different) so that every time the user refreshes the page he gets a different number (set in advance) and text (ie. 900 is the number of birds, 1300 would be the number of cats, 80 the number of dogs, etc). How would I do that?

Many thanks,

```
<p id="dynamic-number">1</p>
<p class="dynamic-text">Number of birds</p>
```

JS:

```
var currentNumber = $('#dynamic-number').text();

$({numberValue: currentNumber}).animate({numberValue: 900}, {
    duration: 2000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function() { 
        $('#dynamic-number').text(Math.ceil(this.numberValue)); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/w346Q/2/

Random Number from Math.random()

Random Message from an Array of messages.

```
var currentNumber = $('#dynamic-number').text();

var randMsg = ["Number of birds", "Aeroplanes flying", "Aliens seen", "Greetings received", "Messages Sent", "Your Personal Message"];

var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * randMsg.length);

$('.dynamic-text').text(randMsg[n]);

var maxNo = 1000;

var randNo = Math.ceil(Math.random() * maxNo);

$({
    numberValue: currentNumber
}).animate({
    numberValue: randNo
}, {
    duration: 2000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function () {
        $('#dynamic-number').text(Math.ceil(this.numberValue));
    }
});
```

You can customize it :

1. Change maximum random no generated by changing  `maxNo`
2. Change your messages or add messages by changing or adding strings to `randMsg` array

---

**UPDATE**

If your numbers are predefined : http://jsfiddle.net/w346Q/4/

```
var currentNumber = $('#dynamic-number').text();

var randMsg = ["Number of birds", "Aeroplanes flying", "Aliens seen", "Greetings received", "Messages Sent", "Your Personal Message"];
var randNo = [800,90,700,99,600,56];

var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * randMsg.length);

$('.dynamic-text').text(randMsg[n]);

$({
    numberValue: currentNumber
}).animate({
    numberValue: randNo[n]
}, {
    duration: 2000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function () {
        $('#dynamic-number').text(Math.ceil(this.numberValue));
    }
});
```

The same can be achieved with the help of json data.

Comment: Thanks a lot! How could I pre define the numbers for "Number of birds", "Aeroplanes flying", "Aliens seen", "Greetings received", "Messages Sent", "Your Personal Message ? (I believe they are set randomly for the moment in your fiddle) Thanks!

Comment: So the number of birds/dogs/cats will be predefined or will be random?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
function changeNumber(txtc,num){
$('#'+txtc).text('1');
var currentNumber = $('#dynamic-number').text();
var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * num) + 1);
$({numberValue: currentNumber}).animate({numberValue: x}, {
    duration: 2000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function() { 
        $('#'+txtc).text(Math.ceil(this.numberValue)); 
    }
});

}

changeNumber('dynamic-number1',900);
changeNumber('dynamic-number2',1300);
changeNumber('dynamic-number3',80);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zQ5AL/3/)**

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But that's not really what I'm looking for, I've now modified my post to make it more clear. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

try that:

html

```
<p id="dynamic-number" class="dynamic-number">1</p>
<p class="dynamic-text">Number of birds</p>
<p id="dynamic-number2"  class="dynamic-number">1</p>
<p class="dynamic-text">Number of Rats</p>
```

css

```
.dynamic-number {
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: red;
    font: bold 35px Arial;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

.dynamic-text {
    font: bold 35px Arial;
    color: blue;
    text-align: left;
}
```

javascript

```
DoAnimation(700,'#dynamic-number');
DoAnimation(500,'#dynamic-number2');
function DoAnimation(nv,id) {
var currentNumber = $(id).text();
$({numberValue: currentNumber}).animate({numberValue: nv}, {
    duration: 2000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function() { 
        $(id).text(Math.ceil(this.numberValue)); 
    }
});
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zQ5AL/1/)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in your example both are displayed at the same time, I'd like a different one each time (not sure if this is possible though). Thanks!